# Error to Adding product "Your shopping cart is empty"

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-3

I'm trying opencart (OC 3.0.2.0, when I add 1 item to the shopping cart, I got the notice: Success: You have added xxxxxx to your shopping cart!, but when I go to shopping cart page, there is nothing. (Your shopping cart is empty!)

ps: I didn't install other extensions.

Image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pF4XR.png

Comment: if you had not complete your development then i will recommenced you to install 3.0.2.1b its cover all issue of 3.0.2.0

Comment: What is your PHP version? Opencart behaves differently with PHP 5.x and 7.x

Comment: Hi, i tried this with the php5 and php7 version without any results, my solution was to go back to an earlier version 2.3.0.2